# Understanding the parameters passed to the array_reduce method

Tags: php

I was just going through [this online tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=obHJxnQVDsU), and I see the below script:

```
<?php

include_once 'renderer.php';

class Page {
    
    protected $renderers;
    
    public function add($renderer) {
        $this->renderers[] = $renderer;
    }
    
    public function render() {
    
        $content = '';
        $content .= "--Start of page--\n";
        $content .= array_reduce($this->renderers , function($output , $r){
            return $output .= $r->render()."\n";
        } , '');
        $content .= "--End of page--\n";
        
        return $content;
    }
    
}

$page = new Page();

$page->add(new BlogRenderer());
$page->add(new ArticleRenderer());

echo $page->render();
```

Let's zoom in to the the call to the array_reduce() call:

```
 $content .= array_reduce($this->renderers , function($output , $r){
                return $output .= $r->render()."\n";
            } , '');
```

I have 2 really fundamental questions here, what are there two parameters being passed to the array_reduce function and when did `render()` become a property of `$r` , for the call to `$r->render()` to be valid? How is that call valid?

I have seen the PHP manual on the [array_reduce](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php) method, but the way this method gets used here baffles me.

Comment: Check http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php

Comment: @b0s3 saw that ..not i understand the general usage , i don't understand the usage in the current context .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***What are there two parameters being passed to the `array_reduce` function?***

The first parameter is an array with 2 elements (an instance of `BlogRenderer()` and an instance of `ArticleRenderer()`).

The second parameter is a callback function.

***When did `render()` become a property of `$r`?***

The callback has 2 parameters, the second parameter `$r` holds the value of the current iteration. That would be an instance of `BlogRenderer()` or `ArticleRenderer()` so in the classes `BlogRenderer()` and `ArticleRenderer()` there is a method called `render()`

I hope this makes sense.

Comment: check out this fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/y6pru3rf/ , why is the value of $o always nothing ? its blank ? why ?

Comment: Jsfiddle can't execute PHP code only javascript. Try 3v4l.org or phptester.net

Comment: You can't try 3v4l.org